# Raspberry Pi Camera and OpenCV: can't open camera by index

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi4, python

I've got a weird problem:

I've installed the OpenCV lib on my Pi. I have a Pi Cam connexted to the Pi (i am able to list all video devices and am able to take a picture with raspistill)

But when i try to take a video feed from opencv with python

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
```

I get the error:

```
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-wheel-qd18ncao/opencv-python/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
```

I tried it with different index (from -1 up to 13) but nothing works.

Any hints ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem, try to specify the video backend, like:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(index, cv2.CAP_V4L)
```

Index can be set to -1 to be automatically detected.
You should also need to enable this module if your raspberry is not recent:

> sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2

Take also a look [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/19356), where a similar problem is described.

Comment: Hi, tried this already and still not working

Comment: Try this 2 things: 1) set the index to -1, 2) Enable camera module with sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2

Comment: Look also here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/19356

Comment: That worked for me :  cv2.VideoCapture(-1,2). Thanks for the Link and the Hint ! Can you edit your Post so i can mark it as the answer ?